# How to bind IIS Express so it handles requests made to ethernet adaptor?

Tags: windows, networking, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I'm sharing a wifi connection from a Windows computer to a Mac through their ethernet adaptors, and I'm trying to setup IIS Express so it listens for requests being made from my Mac to the Windows ethernet address on port 64550. I'm getting a status 503 Service Unavailable error on Mac when attempting the request, however.

I'm not really sure what to bind IIS Express to. I've tried `*:64550:localhost`, `*:64550:127.0.0.1`, and `*:64550:<ethernet-adaptor-address>` with no luck.

I should note that I have also setup the advanced internet sharing settings in Windows to allow access to the service, where the internal/external ports are set to 64550 and each of the ip addresses just mentioned I've tried using as the service host ip, so I believe there should be a firewall rule created allowing access.

I should also note that I'm able to successfully make requests to IIS Express with a different network configuration, where both computers access internet through same wifi router and the router forwards requests to 64550 to Windows computer.

I'm using Windows 10, Mac OS 10, and Visual Studio Community 2015 (.NET Framework 4.6) with IIS Express version 10.0.10557.1000.

Comment: Typically you should not share the connection to Mac as that's essentially a special networking setup. You already know how to get things right by connecting both machines to the same WIFI, so I assume this is not a big deal any more.

Comment: @LexLi Problem is I'm trying to do this for a network I don't have control over so I can't setup forwarding.